# How to get shipping price with Woocomerce API?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, shipping-method

I am developing an application allowing customers of an online store to purchase products.
I have to base myself on the already existing Wordpress site, which uses the Woocommerce plugin.

I use [the API REST of Woocomerce](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#) and I want to recover the delivery methods. For this we can use the endpoint *"shipping/zones/1/methods"* of API.

**The problem:**
I recover the different delivery methods well but on some methods, I do not recover the delivery costs (I need it to display it to the customer).

In the result of the API request, we see that for the "Colissimo avec signature" method, I have the costs but not for "Mondial Relay":

```js
[
{
        "id": 5,
        "instance_id": 5,
        "title": "Colissimo avec signature",
        "order": 4,
        "enabled": true,
        "method_id": "lpc_sign",
        "method_title": "Colissimo avec signature",
        "method_description": "<p>Une signature sera nécessaire à la livraison</p>\n",
        "settings": {
            "title": {
                "id": "title",
                "label": "Titre",
                "description": "Nom de la méthode de livraison que le client verra sur le tunnel de commande.",
                "type": "text",
                "value": "Colissimo avec signature",
                "default": "Colissimo avec signature",
                "tip": "Nom de la méthode de livraison que le client verra sur le tunnel de commande.",
                "placeholder": ""
            },
            "title_free": {
                "id": "title_free",
                "label": "Titre si gratuit",
                "description": "Nom de la méthode de livraison que le client verra sur le tunnel de commande si la méthode est gratuite. Laissez vide pour garder toujours le titre standard.",
                "type": "text",
                "value": null,
                "default": "",
                "tip": "Nom de la méthode de livraison que le client verra sur le tunnel de commande si la méthode est gratuite. Laissez vide pour garder toujours le titre standard.",
                "placeholder": ""
            },
            "shipping_rates": {
                "id": "shipping_rates",
                "label": "Frais",
                "description": "Frais selon le poids",
                "type": "shipping_rates",
                "value": [
                    {
                        "min_weight": 0,
                        "max_weight": 0.25,
                        "min_price": 0,
                        "max_price": 10000,
                        "shipping_class": [
                            "all"
                        ],
                        "price": 6.7
                    },
                    {
                        "min_weight": 0.25,
                        "max_weight": 0.5,
                        "min_price": 0,
                        "max_price": 10000,
                        "shipping_class": [
                            "all"
                        ],
                        "price": 7.4
                    },
                    {
                        "min_weight": 0.5,
                        "max_weight": 0.75,
                        "min_price": 0,
                        "max_price": 10000,
                        "shipping_class": [
                            "all"
                        ],
                        "price": 8.2
                    },
                    {
                        "min_weight": 0.75,
                        "max_weight": 0.75,
                        "min_price": 0,
                        "max_price": 10000,
                        "shipping_class": [
                            "all"
                        ],
                        "price": 8.75
                    },
                    {
                        "min_weight": 0.1,
                        "max_weight": 0.2,
                        "min_price": 0,
                        "max_price": 10000,
                        "shipping_class": [
                            "all"
                        ],
                        "price": 9.6
                    },
                    {
                        "min_weight": 0.2,
                        "max_weight": 0.3,
                        "min_price": 0,
                        "max_price": 10000,
                        "shipping_class": [
                            "all"
                        ],
                        "price": 10.44
                    },
                    {
                        "min_weight": 0.3,
                        "max_weight": 0.4,
                        "min_price": 0,
                        "max_price": 10000,
                        "shipping_class": [
                            "all"
                        ],
                        "price": 11.29
                    },
                    {
                        "min_weight": 0.4,
                        "max_weight": 0.5,
                        "min_price": 0,
                        "max_price": 10000,
                        "shipping_class": [
                            "all"
                        ],
                        "price": 12.13
                    }
                ],
                "default": "",
                "tip": "Frais selon le poids",
                "placeholder": ""
            }
        },

    },
 {
        "id": 11,
        "instance_id": 11,
        "title": "Mondial relay",
        "order": 4,
        "enabled": true,
        "method_id": "flexible_shipping",
        "method_title": "Flexible Shipping",
        "method_description": "<p>Flexible Shipping</p>\n",
        "settings": {
            "0": {
                "id": 0,
                "label": "Flexible Shipping",
                "description": "See how to <a href=\"https://docs.flexibleshipping.com/collection/20-fs-table-rate/?utm_source=flexible-shipping-settings&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=flexible-shipping-docs-link\" target=\"_blank\">configure Flexible Shipping</a>.",
                "type": "title",
                "value": "",
                "default": "",
                "tip": "See how to <a href=\"https://docs.flexibleshipping.com/collection/20-fs-table-rate/?utm_source=flexible-shipping-settings&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=flexible-shipping-docs-link\" target=\"_blank\">configure Flexible Shipping</a>.",
                "placeholder": ""
            },
            "title": {
                "id": "title",
                "label": "Shipping title",
                "description": "Visible only to admin in WooCommerce settings.",
                "type": "text",
                "value": "Mondial relay",
                "default": "Flexible Shipping",
                "tip": "Visible only to admin in WooCommerce settings.",
                "placeholder": ""
            },
            "tax_status": {
                "id": "tax_status",
                "label": "Tax Status",
                "description": "",
                "type": "select",
                "value": "none",
                "default": "taxable",
                "tip": "",
                "placeholder": "",
                "options": {
                    "taxable": "Taxable",
                    "none": "Aucune"
                }
            },
            "title_shipping_methods": {
                "id": "title_shipping_methods",
                "label": "Shipping Methods",
                "description": "",
                "type": "title_shipping_methods",
                "value": "",
                "default": "",
                "tip": "",
                "placeholder": ""
            },
            "shipping_methods": {
                "id": "shipping_methods",
                "label": "Shipping Methods",
                "description": "",
                "type": "shipping_methods",
                "value": "",
                "default": "",
                "tip": "",
                "placeholder": ""
            }
        },
]
```

I want to clarify that Woocomerce is well configured and on [the website](https://lyoncaps.com/) it works correctly.

Do you have a solution ?
If not, do you have any other alternative?

Otherwise, I intend to mark the delivery costs in hard, in the application. I know, it's not good but I count on your help to offer me a better solution.

Thank you in advance !PI

Comment: you need to pass the cost to the selected method call. This link will clear more https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#update-a-shipping-method-of-a-shipping-zone

Comment: This dont works. It return the same result.